# math functions in thread returning wrong values, with android ndk

Tags: android, c++, math, android-ndk, math.h

I am having an issue while trying to port a code to Android NDK, which is doing fine on iOS.
The code renders 3D models and uses openGL ES 1.1 for that, so it performs many calculations using the standard c math library (including math.h).

Here is a snippet of the code used to test the anomaly:

```
double e;
e = sqrt(25);
assert(e == 5);
e = sqrt(16);
assert(e == 4);
e = sqrt(9);
assert(e == 3);
e = sqrt(4);
assert(e == 2);
e = sqrt(1);
assert(e == 1);
e = sqrt(0);
assert(e == 0);
```

These asserts work fust fine anywhere, while this:

```
int vec[10] = {0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81};
int res[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
double d;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    d = sqrt(vec[i]);
    assert(d == res[i]);
}
```

crashes on any thread other than the main one. For example, it returns me 0.37500000008731149 as the sqrt(0), which is why the first assert on the for loop fails.

It seems that the problem lies on the calculations using the content of the variables, not the calculations on hardcoded values. May that be a problem about memory mapping on the different threads? I debugged it, and printed the values of vec[i], though, and those are correct.

Does math library have any issues when used in different threads? can you give me another explanation why this is behaving so weird?

EDIT: I have also seen the same weird behaviour with other math functions, such as pow() and sin(). Plus, I also tried sqrtf and powf. They both seem to give different, but also wrong, values than their double counterparts.

Comment: do you syncronize your threads? Is it possible that other threads access your for loop at the same time?

Comment: Just to confirm: Your code is compiled as C++, not C? And you are very sure that you do include `math.h`? The reason I'm asking is that C lets you get away with calling undeclared functions, defaulting to a function returning an `int`. Since these functions obviously don't return `int`, you would get wrong results. Also, you are passing `int` arguments to functions expecting `double` arguments. There will be an automatic cast if the proper function prototype is included. But if for some reason it's not, you could get bad results.

Comment: @DenisZaikin, I am starting the threads with java AsyncTasks, with doInBackground method. I don't know if that may give any issue on memory acesses, but the values are correct just before sqrt (e.g., vec[0] gives 0 at any thread at any point)

Comment: @RetoKoradi I am compiling using c++; the code uses C++ classes and methods, not C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally got to some conclusion about how to "solve" the problem, though I am kinda lost why this was happening in the first place.

I am actually coding an app which links to several c++ libraries, which is the common code between iOS and Android apps. When the math calculations are performed inside those libraries,  math returns those wrong values. I believe it is not a problem about threading, but one about scopes of libraries and linkage. The problem vanished when I compiled all the libraries inside the app as those were another CPP sources. This, though, it is not the best way to go, since breaks the modularity of the libs. I'll have to fix that, but that would be a very different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
d == res[i]
```

Here is your problem. Aside from the fact that you're comparing a double and an int and have no idea which one will be casted to the other's type, you're comparing floating point numbers with the == operator.

Comparing floats and doubles doesn't work like this because

```
4.00000000000001 == 4.0
```

will return false, and floating point arithmetic is NOT perfect, and things like sqrt(16) may not necessarily return exactly 4.

Instead of using the == operator, use a function like this (I haven't tested if this compiles)

```
bool AreEqual(double a, double b)
{
  return a < b + 0.00001 && a > b - 0.00001;
}
```

instead.

Comment: The poster writes that `sqrt(0)` returns 0.37500000008731149. That doesn't look like a rounding problem.

Comment: Well maybe not, but since what I said is still true his code will still not function even if sqrt(0) returned 0.

Comment: Thanks @deek0146, but I have tested this same snippet in the main thread on android and it works nice. Also in iOS at any thread (as I am porting the app to android from iOS). Anyway, that is not the functionality i mean the app to have, computing sqrt(16) is actually really dumb. I used this only to check if the library was performing ok.